# Multiple AWS Instances and Node events

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an implementation in node where an API when called does some processing and waits for an event from another function before returning the response. This works fine when ran locally and when running in a single instance in AWS but when multiple instances are involved there are some issues which I'm assuming is because the API is being called from one instance and the emitter is being emitted in another instance. Is there any way to keep the listeners and emitters same across all instances?

Update :

After some research I found that using an application loadbalancer with some logic for routing can help with this issue. I am marking the answer below as correct because while it did not help me with AWS autoscaling, it did help me find an alernate solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIU you think that event emitted from one process is being handled in a different process, but it never would be the case from what I know because each process has its own memory and also events would be associated with the process only.

I have added a sample code that demonstrates what I meant by it. Maybe if you post the code you are referring to, we could check what went wrong.

```
const cluster = require("cluster");
const EventEmitter = require("events");

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  cluster.fork();
  const myEE = new EventEmitter();
  myEE.on("foo", arg =>
    console.log("emitted from ", arg, "received in master")
  );
  setTimeout(() => {
    myEE.emit("foo", "master");
  }, 1000);
} else {
  const myEE = new EventEmitter();
  myEE.on("foo", arg => console.log("emitted from", arg, "received in worker"));
  setTimeout(() => {
    myEE.emit("foo", "client");
  }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Hi Kiran, I tried this implementation but the issue I'm facing is that if an event is emitted in a fork, then all the other listeners in the other forks should also be able to receive the event and process it. Is this possible?

Comment: @Vinaayakh I think your requirement is different from what you have stated in the question, neverthless I can suggest some solutions for your requirement. Either you can do is send a message from worker using   `process.send(msg);` and let master resend the message to all other workers using `worker.send('hi there');`. or the best and preferred way is to setup a pub/sub using redis(https://redis.io/topics/pubsub) or node-ipc(https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ipc). Please refer this for more idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55400905/nodejs-process-communication-via-a-text-file