# NodeJS process communication - (via a text file?)

Tags: node.js

**Scenario**: A number of NodeJS processes running on several VMs need to communicate with a master process in a time-critical manner. Communication is occasionally at a high frequency.

**Solution**: Processes append messages to a single text file stored on shared storage which is processed and cleaned by the master.

**Implementation** approach so far:

Stage 1: Processes use `fs.createWriteStream().write(msg+'\n')` to minimize the changes of one process overwriting another process's update.

Stage 2: Master uses `fs.watch().on(processChange(e,f))` used to pick up changes.

Stage 3: Messages are processed and removed by the master using:

```
processChange(e, f) {
    const NewMsgs = fs.readFileSync(f).toString().split('\n');
    fs.writeFileSync(f,'');
    // now process NewMsgs
}
```

**Questions**:

- Is there a better solution?
- How can I improve my implementation?
- How likely is it that messages will be overwritten during stage 1 and 3?

Comment: Why not a TCP socket?

Comment: Is it a clustered application? I mean are all the child processes basically a fork of the master?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [socket.io](https://socket.io/) - it provides performant cross-application communication without the possibility of losing data due to mishandled concurrent updates to the filesystem and has a great set of "getting started" tutorials.

In addition, it gives you the advantage of being able to distribute the NodeJS processes across different machines - in your current solution, they must all be co-located on a single machine. This will likely help your application scale as its demand grows.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to setup a pub/sub and set the child processes to publish on the channel and let master subscribe and process it in whichever way it wants to. Use something like [Redis Pub/Sub](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub) or [Node-IPC](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ipc).
An example using node-ipc written by [ndelangen](https://gist.github.com/ndelangen)

First Process

```
const ipc = require('node-ipc');

ipc.config.id = 'a-unique-process-name1';
ipc.config.retry = 1500;
ipc.config.silent = true;
ipc.serve(() => ipc.server.on('a-unique-message-name', message => {
  console.log(message);
}));
ipc.server.start();
```

Second process

```
const ipc = require('node-ipc');

ipc.config.id = 'a-unique-process-name2';
ipc.config.retry = 1500;
ipc.config.silent = true;
ipc.connectTo('a-unique-process-name1', () => {
  ipc.of['jest-observer'].on('connect', () => {
    ipc.of['jest-observer'].emit('a-unique-message-name', "The message we send");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I'm considering using socket.io as jakemingolla suggested, which implements pub/sub model. Do you think I would be better off with using Redis Pub/Sub or Node-IPC? If so why?

Comment: Websockets are duplex communication technology basically for  a browser and a server. You can send messages to a server and receive event-driven responses without having to poll the server for a reply. I would suggest Node-IPC if it is nothing complex because Redis Pub/Sub needs you to setup Redis Instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the infrastructural burden of a pub/sub or queue system, may I suggest that instead of appending to a file you'd rather put one file per message into a shared folder, and let the master process watch the folder and process and delete them file by file?

Having multiple processes append to a file while you simultaneously also removing lines sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Given that it sounds like there is no communication back from the master, this should be a viable approach.

What would help you select a solution is if you could state if you favor delivery robustness (meaning, all messages should eventually reach the master), or delivery speed (meaning, delays are not acceptable, but losing data that is deemed old is fine).